# Angular ui-router : Creating a navbar that automatically injects itself to all main states and their child states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My navbar should be on top of almost every page (but not all), so I'm trying to load it for some pages using ui-view, but I'm stuck.

What I'm trying to do is to attach my navbar to main states (like `contacts`, `about`) and their child states (`contacts.list`, `contacts.detail`, etc), but If I do it that way, nav is injected into their main divs so it gets smaller, so I need to attach it into index.html directly.

I copied ui-router's demo app, created a ui-view called navbar, removed navigation part from index.html and created navbar.html.

Here's my plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/i0DuDcocH04TZadim2Oo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't load your plunkr but i already did something like that.

If you want to use a navbar that is independant from the rest you'll need to use views for each part of your main page (like : header / content /foooter).

For that you can  have an index like this :

```
<body>
    <section>
         <div ui-view="header"/>
    </section>
    <section>
         <div ui-view="content"/>
    </section>
</body>
```

Then define your main state

```
$state.state('home', {
    url:'/'
    views:{
        'header':{
             templateUrl:'navbar.html',
             controller:'navbarController'
         },
         'content':{
             templateUrl:'content.html'
             controller:'contentController'
         }
    }
});
```

In your navbar template you have now a dedicated template and controller so you can do whatever you want with it.

If you need to listen for change event for instance :

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    event.preventDefault();
    // transitionTo() promise will be rejected with
    // a 'transition prevented' error
})
```

from : http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

The $rootScope is normal, events are only broadcasted through $rootScope.

If you need to pass data between the view you have to stored your variable in the $rootScope. I searched for other way to do it but it's just to much way simplier and enough to use the $rootScope for this.

If ypou want to add some classes when some state (or children) are active you can use the directive ui-sref-active : http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active. Directive ui-sref-active-eq for strict equality.

When using views you will have a trouble about using subState if you don't want using your app in full view but just normal state with template and controller. The best for that is to have an intermediate state wit a view define like this :

```
views:{
    '@':{
         template:'<div ui-view/>'
    }
}
```

Then you can define children of this state normally without using views.

Though i can really say if that's what you're searching for without loading your plunkr i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would have two sets of nested states. For the `main.xx` group you would inject your navbar and create nested states from there. Then each non-nav partial would have it's own  set of states. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZDHkFz3fQmXniqrYh7Is) is an example.